# Console output of "Powershell" Jenkins step appears with delay

Tags: powershell, output, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline. One of the steps is `powershell` which executes a powershell script. The script contains several `Echo` statements that should inform about the script execution.

I'd expect the texts issued with `Echo` to immediately appear in the Jenkins job's console.

The problem is that they do appear but delayed. I have an impression that the output is postponed until the script has finished its work. But that makes those echo calls useless.

How can I achieve that what I write with Echo appears immediately in the Jenkins job's console?

Actually, the Jenkins job used windows bat until recently, and then all the echo calls appeared immediately in Jenkins. Then I changed to Powershell (because I wanted to do some things in parallel), and now experience the problem.

I have read about the many CmdLets that can be used (`Write-Verbose`, `Write-Information` etc.) and tried them, but the effect is the same: The ouput apperars but delayed. Write-Host is not allowed in Jenkins jobs and is generally considered not well suited for the task.

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Echo is just a alias in Powershell, in fact it doesnt run the bash 'echo' command, it runs a CMDLet.
With the Command: `Get-Alias | ? {$_.name -like "echo*"}` your can see, witch CMDLet is used instead 'Write-Output'.
To list all Alias you can run `Get-Alias`

Try the Output with the .Net method:

```
[system.console]::WriteLine("My Output")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it did not help. I tried it like this:

    `[Console]::WriteLine("Hello")`
    `[Console]::Out.Flush()`

But there was no output at all (in Jenkins).